# Oracle Weblogic Portal Eclipse oepe_11gR1PS4 hangs while developing "Discovering controls"

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, portal

In the configuration folder, getting the following as log, and in eclipse it hangs with discovering controls. Also while building the project, eclipse hangs. Please suggest a solution to this problem.

```
!SESSION 2015-05-18 11:50:46.623 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1200
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-05-18 11:50:52.174
!MESSAGE The -clean (osgi.clean) option was not successful. Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Oracle\Middleware\oepe_11gR1PS4\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-05-18 11:58:06.286
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.createHandle(Composite.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createHandle(Decorations.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
```

Comment: `Unable to clean the storage area: C:\Oracle\Middleware\oepe_11gR1PS4\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi` ... what are the file permissions? Who are you installing as?

Comment: spelling and grammar